# Issue using textscan() on Octave 4.0.0 (installed with Homebrew at OS X 10.11.3 - El Capitan)

Tags: macos, matlab, homebrew, octave, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to compile the following octave 4.0.0 code (called 'looptest.m'):

```
fid_Tv = fopen('Tv.txt');
fid_Ti = fopen('Ti.txt');
Tv_matrix = textscan(fid_Tv,'%f%f%c%f','headerlines',1);
Ti_matrix = textscan(fid_Ti,'%f%f%c%f','headerlines',1);
fclose('all');
```

This code works fine on Matlab, but Octave returns this:

```
error: strread: %q, %c, %[] or bit width format specifiers are not supported yet.
error: called from
    strread at line 319 column 7
    textscan at line 318 column 8
    looptest at line 3 column 11
```

Can someone help me to fix this please?

Comment: I think @Daniel is suggesting `%s` instead of `%c`. You could also try `%1s` to force single character strings.

Comment: Stupid autocorrect, delete nonsens. Yes that was what I intended to write.